# How can I change appearance of checkbox button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I need to change appearance of my checkbox button, precisely i need to place custom background image instead of regular gray square.

Now I tried something like this:

```
[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: url("../images/checkbox.png")
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-image: url("../images/checkbox-c.png")
}
```

and it works fine for when checked but while idle it does not change background image to checkbox.png it remains simple gray square.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: There are some sites that can help you with this, example: [http://www.csscheckbox.com/](http://www.csscheckbox.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i don't know why other answer has been deleted but that is most likely to work as it worked for me here:

```css
[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    -webkit-appearance: none; /*<----this needs to be added here.*/
    background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/unchecked_checkbox.png")
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/checked_checkbox.png")
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because the OP said that it didn't work for him and I believed him.

Comment: Neither do I, I did not deleted it. It works fine, thank you :)

Comment: Danield I tried it and it did not worked, now i tried Jai's and it works for some reason lol

Comment: @Danield actually you have deleted your answer and i was posting an js fiddle there at your comment area and i was not able to because the post had been deleted, then i added this answer with snippet.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of approaches, typically involving styling an element which follows the checkbox, on the `:checked` state, hiding the checkbox, and leveraging off the native behaviour of a `label` to wrap the result.

```css
label {
  position: relative; /* <-- usually handy to have for styling */
}
label input {
  display: none; /* <-- hide the default checkbox */
}
label span { /* <-- style the artificial checkbox */
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
[type=checkbox]:checked+ span { /* <-- style its checked state */
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type='checkbox'><span></span> Checkbox label</label>
```